# Wizard Form jQuery 'next' button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've just integrated a multi-step form using jQuery, but the 'next' button doesn't work for me. 
I think it's related to my js file, but I don't know for sure... Thanks for your help

You can find the example at [thecodeplayer.com](http://thecodeplayer.com)

**Index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Test JQ </title>
<script src="ms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ms.css" type="text/css" />
<head>
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li>Social Profiles</li>
        <li>Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
        <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
        <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
        <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**.js file:**

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Define _"doesn't work"_. Does the button throw an error in the console? Is it disabled? Does the click even fire?...

Answer (score 0):

Please copy the below codes in a new JS file and include that file after "jquery.easing.min.js".

The JS codes start below:

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```